# Can't search for the max value into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, class, methods

My problem is that i can't search into an array using linq in order to find an object property and set that as an id.

I need the method to search in the array for other `model.idCliente` and set that value as the "nextid + 1", in order to use it as id and the next array index.

Since the array's empty, the program adds the new object correctly, but when entering in the else if case, i get an axception for "a as null".

This is my code (where i get an exception on the else if linq line saying that "a" is null):

```
        //Arrays

    ClienteModel[] MemoryClienti = new ClienteModel[19];
    OrdineModel[] MemoryOrdini = new OrdineModel[19];

    //Aggiungi

    public bool CreateCliente(ClienteModel model)
    {
            if (MemoryClienti[0] == null)
            { 
                int defaultID = 0;
                int defaultIndex = 0;
                model.IDCliente = defaultID;
                MemoryClienti[defaultIndex] = model;
            }
            else if (MemoryClienti[0]!=null)
            {
                var maxID = MemoryClienti.Max(a => a.IDCliente);
                model.IDCliente = maxID++;
                MemoryClienti[maxID++] = model;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

This is the code of the form click:

```
        //Aggiungi Cliente
    private void aggiungiClienteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clienteModel.Cognome = cognomeTextBox.Text;
        clienteModel.Nome = nomeTextBox.Text;
        clienteModel.Indirizzo = indirizzoTextbox.Text;
        dbMemoryManager.CreateCliente(clienteModel);
        MessageBox.Show("Cliente aggiunto correttamente.");
        cognomeTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
        nomeTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
        indirizzoTextbox.Text = String.Empty;
    }
```

This is the `ClienteModel` class:

```
    public class ClienteModel
{
    public int IDCliente { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Indirizzo { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: When you create your array, it gets filled with the default values for the type (`ClienteModel`).  Assuming that's a class, the default value in the array is a null reference.  Even though you have an entry in the zero slot of the array, the other slots are null.  So when you run that code, every slot but one is null and so `a.IDCliente` will fail.  Consider using a `List<ClienteModel>` rather than an array - it makes much more sense here

Comment: Interesting, so (theorically) the entire array should be filled? How should i use the list? i tried with list.add but everytime it overwrite the previous object. Ex: [0] a b c, when i enter add another object ( d e f ) created from textbox and method i have [0] d e f, [1] d e f.

Comment: Always favor List<T> over an array : `var yourlist = new List<ClienteModel>(); .... yourlist .Add(someClienteModel); `

Comment: As i said, using the .add method, the list is overwritten with the newest object, so i have 2 same objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't the following code achieve what you are trying to do?

```
ClienteModel[] MemoryClienti = new ClienteModel[19];
OrdineModel[] MemoryOrdini = new OrdineModel[19];
int maxID = 0; /* 0 is not a valid ID. IDs start from 1 */


//Aggiungi
public bool CreateCliente(ClienteModel model)
{
    if(maxID <= MemoryClienti.Length) {
      MemoryClienti[maxID++] = model;    // copy the reference
      model.IDCliente = maxID;           // update the object's ID
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;                      // can't add. array is full
    }
}
```

If you are also doing deletions, you are better off using a List as others have also suggested.

Comment: Seems like it's working, but when you insert the 2nd element, the first one is replaced by the 2nd... i don't know why, happens with list.add too.